# Why is it recommended to derive from Exception instead of BaseException class in Python?

Tags: python, exception

The [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#module-exceptions) says that "programmers are encouraged to derive new exceptions from the Exception class or one of its subclasses, and not from BaseException". Without any further explanation as to why.

I am curious as to why it is recommended this way? Is it just to preserve the [exceptions hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) as Python developers envisioned it?

```py
>>> dir(BaseException) == dir(Exception)
True
```

Comment: [PEP 352](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/) pretty much explains it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Exceptions derived from `BaseException` are: `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`.

According to the documentation:

- [`GeneratorExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit): Raised when a generator‘s close() method is called. It directly inherits from BaseException instead of StandardError since it is technically not an error.
- [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt): Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally Control-C or Delete). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly. Interrupts typed when a built-in function input() or raw_input() is waiting for input also raise this exception. **The exception inherits from BaseException so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches Exception and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting.**
- [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit): The exception inherits from BaseException instead of StandardError or Exception so that it is not accidentally caught by code that catches Exception. **This allows the exception to properly propagate up and cause the interpreter to exit.**

So the usual reasons are to prevent `try ... except Exception` accidently prevent interpreter exit (except `GeneratorExit`)

**UPDATE** after seeing  Ashwini Chaudhary's comment:

[PEP 352 - Required Superclass for Exceptions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/) explains the reason.

> With the exception hierarchy now even more important since it has a
>   basic root, a change to the existing hierarchy is called for. As it
>   stands now, if one wants to catch all exceptions that signal an error
>   and do not mean the interpreter should be allowed to exit, you must
>   specify all but two exceptions specifically in an except clause or
>   catch the two exceptions separately and then re-raise them and have
>   all other exceptions fall through to a bare except clause:
>
> ```
> except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
>     raise
> except:
>     ...
> ```
>
> That is needlessly explicit. This PEP proposes moving
>   KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit to inherit directly from
>   BaseException.